# Finding conformal mapping from $S=\{z=x+iy: xy>2, x>0\}$ to unit disc $\mathbb D$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I know the formula of conformal mapping between upper half plane $\mathbb H$ and unit disc $\mathbb D$, so it would be sufficient to find a conformal mapping between the region $\{z=x+iy: xy>2, x>0\}$ and $\mathbb H$.

I first attempted to rotate $S$ by $-45^{\circ}$ and apply [Conformal mapping $z+\frac{1}{z}$, how to see the mapping to hyperbolas?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640668/conformal-mapping-z-frac1z-how-to-see-the-mapping-to-hyperbolas) , but this did not work.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603142/conformal-mappings-from-xy-1-to-the-upper-half-plane

Comment: Maybe this will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply $w=z^2$ maps $S$ onto $\mathbb{H}^\prime=\{w\mid \operatorname{Im}w>4\}$
, so $$w=z^2-4i$$ maps $S$ onto $\mathbb{H}$.

Of course there is an approach to obtain the mapping $w=z^2-4i$ using mapping properties of $z+\frac{1}{z}$, however, it is very complicated.

To use mapping properties of $z+\frac{1}{z}$ is an essential way if you want to obtain a mapping function of $\{z=x+iy\mid xy<2\}$ to $\mathbb{H}.$